# Is it secure to use exec() PHP

Tags: php, exec

I wondering if is good (or bad), to use exec() command in PHP ...
For example, with API Paypal REST, I use exec() (with curl) rather than the curl from PHP

```
$a = exec('curl -v '.$this->ENDPOINT.'/v1/oauth2/token \
           -H "Accept: application/json" \
           -H "Accept-Language: fr_FR" \
           -u "'.$this->CLIENTID.':'.$this->SECRET.'" \
           -d "grant_type=client_credentials"'
          );
$a = json_decode($a);
```

What is the impact? Is it better not to do?
Thanks guys

Comment: Is it possible by the user to change the value of `ENDPOINT, CLIENTID, SECRET` ?

Comment: No, the values ​​are not editable by the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those parameters are not coming from an end-user then you are **pretty-safe**. If not, then you should definitely filter them through [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg)

#### The secure code..

```
$a = exec('curl -v '.escapeshellarg($this->ENDPOINT).'/v1/oauth2/token \
           -H "Accept: application/json" \
           -H "Accept-Language: fr_FR" \
           -u "'.escapeshellarg($this->CLIENTID).':'.escapeshellarg($this->SECRET).'" \
           -d "grant_type=client_credentials"'
);
$a = json_decode($a);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you (and the values ​​are not editable by the user).